# Markov's and Tchebychev's Inequality to find Upper Bound

Tags: probability

I'm not sure how to solve this problem:

C = random variable; the number of heads in 100 independent fair coin flips
Find E(C) and V(C). 
Find the upper bounds on P(C >75), using Markov's Inequality and Tchebychev's Inequality.

I understand how to get E(C) (which I believe is 50), but I'm confused on how to complete the rest.

Comment: So, this means you do not know the definition of the variance?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand variance. I'm not sure how to find the upper bound on P(C>75).

Comment: Then show the variance. Next, do you know the definition of Markov inequality?

Comment: Markov's Inequality: P(X >= t) <= (E(X)/t)

Comment: You did not show the variance. Anyway, simply filling the blanks in Markov inequality (X=C, t=75, E(X)=50) yields this part of the answer. Next, same thing with Chebyshev, do you know the definition of the inequality?

Comment: Variance = npq.  

Chebyshev = P(abs(X-mean) >= k*std) = (1/k^2).  

Thank you for the explanation. I didn't know how to use the Markov's Inequality.

Comment: If you reached a full answer, a good practice is to post it here and even, after a while, to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

$C$ is distributed according to the binomial distribution with probability $p$, which I assume is $1/2$ in this case.

According to
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution
we have $E(C)=np$ which in your case is indeed 50. Furthermore, $V(C)=np(1-p)$.

You can use the Markov inequality
$$P(X\geq a)\leq a^{-1} E(X)$$ to calculate an upper bound to $P(C>75)$ since you already know $E(C)$.

Comment: Do we just substitute a for 75?

Comment: It depends whether you really have a strict inequality $C>75$. Then you should consider $P(C>75)=P(C\geq 76)\leq50/76$

Answer (score 0):

You should have have $E[C]=50$ and $Var(C)=25$.

Dima McGreen has shown Markov's inequality gives $P(C \gt 75) \lt \tfrac{50}{75}$ or $P(C \ge 76) \le \tfrac{50}{76}$

For Chebyshev's inequality, note $75 = 50 + 5 \times \sqrt{25}$, and

- either use the two-sided $P\left(|X-\mu_X| \gt k\sigma_X \right) \lt \tfrac{1}{k^2}$ in this case $P\left(|C-50| \gt 25\right) \lt \tfrac{1}{5^2}=\tfrac{1}{25}$
- or the one sided $P\left(X-\mu_X \gt k\sigma_X \right) \lt \tfrac{1}{k^2+1}$ in this case $P\left({C-50} \gt 25\right) \lt \tfrac{1}{5^2+1}=\tfrac{1}{26}$.

Again you could marginally improve this by looking at $P(C \ge 76)$.

So the Chebyshev inequality gives a substantially tighter bound than the Markov inequality.  But this is still very loose.  In fact, using the binomial distribution, $P(C \gt 75)$ is slightly less than $0.0000001$.